# TeX resources for philosophers

Tags: big-list, tex-general

What TeX resources are there that are aimed at the field philosophy?

I already know of [PhilTeX](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/) and [LaTeX for logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/).

Comment: The link to PhilTex seems broken. Does anyone have an up-to-date url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- There's a TeX showcase: [Humanities books typeset with TeX](http://www.tsengbooks.com/).
- [LaTeX for philosophers](http://gregorywheeler.org/latex/phil-style.html) by Gregory Wheeler
- [LaTeX: A guide for philosophers](https://github.com/charlietanksley/charlietanksley_net/raw/8c57def5a843fe82e54fc60af1497ce93d8f3b20/source/pdfs/latex-guide.pdf) by Charlie Tanksley
- A blog post which turned into an interesting discussion: [LaTeX on The Philosophy Smoker](http://philosophysmoker.blogspot.com/2010/06/title-latex.html)

Comment: Note that `philosophy.sty` is not a recommended package for philosophers using LaTeX. Rather, it is a package for philosophers using LaTeX who are forced to deal with editors who insist that their manuscripts 'look as if they were produced in Word'. (And, yes, this really is a requirement of some places and, yes, it makes even less sense than 'We only take Word'.) It does this very well. (At least, it satisfied a place that demanded this of me.) It is based on the 'brain dead' package but extends it a bit.